# Validating a hidden control in javascript when it becomes visible

Tags: jquery, asp.net

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#txtDataFileName').keydown(function (e) {
            if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
                if (e.shiftKey || e.ctrlKey || e.altKey || e.which === 32 && !this.value.length) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
                else {
                    var key = e.keyCode;
                    var name = document.getElementById('<%=txtDataFileName.ClientID %>').value;
                    if (!((key == 8) || (key == 32) || (key == 42) || (key >= 35 && key <= 40) || (key >= 65 && key <= 90) || (key >= 48 && key <= 57) || (key >= 96 && key <= 105))) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        if (name.length < 50 || key == 8) {
                            return true;
                        }
                        else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

txtDataFileName is my control where in display is set as none initially. On a dropdownselection, the txtdatafilename displays as block. But still the validation in javascript is not working..

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Do you have see the source of the html, is this `txtDataFileName` the final id of the control ? or you need to use the `<%=txtDataFileName.ClientID%>` ? and in your code you get it two times, the same id with diferent way.

Comment: How does that make a difference?

Comment: It makes a difference, because ASP.NET might alter the id of the component when it's being rendered as a server control (runat="server"). In that case, your selector can't find the textfield, because its id is different.

You could use _$("[id$=txtDataFileName]")_ as selector instead, which selects all elements with id's **ending** with _txtDataFileName_.

Comment: I used the event under pageLoad function. that works.